# Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I just switched to Ubuntu & Rider from Windows and VS 22 and I'm having a hard time running "update-database" like I was in VS 22.

I tried doing it using Dotnet CLI. I went into the root folder of my project, then I did:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

and I got

```
Specify which project file to use because this '/home/octavian/RiderProjects/mediere-api' contains more than one project file.
```

I tried running

```
dotnet restore
```

and I get the same.

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.
```

When I do a ls -a, here's what I get:

```
.                             appsettings.json  DataLayer                    docker-compose.yml   .dockerignore  .gitignore  Mappers             Migrations  Program.cs
..                            bin               docker-compose.dcproj        Dockerfile           Dtos           Helpers     mediere-API.csproj  obj         Properties
appsettings.Development.json  Controllers       docker-compose.override.yml  Dockerfile.original  .git           .idea       mediere-API.sln     Processors  Requests
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error because I only have one .csproj file.

What can I do to fix it?

Is there any chance that I didn't install all the requirements?

I only installed this after installing Rider

```
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download#linuxubuntu
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try looking at the docs for that command? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options

Comment: @DavidG yes. I tried doing dotnet ef database update -p . -s . and I get the same

Comment: Did you try specifying the project file using the "--project" command line option?

Comment: dotnet ef database update --project . and dotnet ef database update --project mediere-API.csproj too, yes

Comment: The dotnet Tool also has a verbose commandline option.

Comment: What should I do in this case?

Comment: Update: if I do dotnet run it doesn't work either. But if I do dotnet run --project mediere-API.csproj it does. But when I do dotnet ef --project mediere-API.csproj I get the same error

Comment: In your Folder is a `mediere-API.csproj` as well as a `mediere-API.sln` probably because you chose to create the solution file (.sln) in the same folder as the Project. Even though they both point to the same Project dotnet cannot disambiguate by itself which to use. That's why it is asking you which of the 2 you want to use as your Starting Point. You can use `--project <filename>` to specify the file to use. Also have a look at the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run)

Comment: @SeverinJaeschke - FWIW, `dotnet ef` doesn't have any trouble with my project that has both a `.csproj` and a `.sln` containing that project.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That is because dotnet ef is a different tool, which only executes against singular projects (or possibly 2 when using different Startup Project) it never runs against a solution. Therefore it is not ambiguous.

Comment: @SeverinJaeschke - Isn't the question above using `dotnet ef`? The command at the top is `dotnet ef database update`.